# Eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix over an arbitrary field

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have an orthogonal matrix $A$ (i.e. $AA^T = E$) over an arbitrary field $\mathbb k$ ($char$ $\mathbb k \ne 2$, algebraically closed if it is needed) and $\det A = -1$. Is it possible that this matrix does not have an eigenvalue which equals to $-1$? (In the case $\mathbb k = \mathbb R$ it always does)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $spectrum(A)=spectrum(A^T)=((\lambda_i)_{i\leq n})$; moreover $A,A^T$ commute and consequently, are simultaneously triangularizable over  $\overline{K}$, the algebraic closure of $K$. Thus there is a permutation $(\lambda_{p_i})$ of the $(\lambda_i)$ s.t., for every $i$, $\lambda_i\lambda_{p_i}=1$ (this permutation may be not unique because the $(\lambda_i)$ are not necessarily distinct). Then $spectrum(A)$ is in the form $\{\lambda_1,1/\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k,1/\lambda_k,1,\cdots,1,-1,\cdots,-1\}$. Since $\det(A)=-1$, $A$ admits the eigenvalue $-1$ with odd multiplicity and $A+I_n$ is singular.

Comment: Well done!!!${}{}$

Comment: @  Omnomnomnom , thanks. Moreover, when $K$ is a finite field, the number of orthogonal matrices is known.  cf.  http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317262?seq=10#page_scan_tab_contents